# Solve Cauchy-Euler Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve $x^2 y" +xy' +4y = \sin (2\ln x)$, $x>0$, by means of substitution $x= e^t$

Comment: Do you know how to find the homogeneous solution?

Answer (score 0):

As you look for a solution $$
z(t) = y(e^t)
$$
you compute
$$
z'(t) = e^t y'(e^t)  \\
z''(t) = e^t y'(e^t) +  e^{2t} y''(e^t)
$$
so the equation becomes
$$
x^2y''(x)+xy'(x)+4y(x)=\sin(2\ln x)\\\to
e^{2t} y''(e^t)+e^t y'(e^t)+4y(e^t)=\sin(2t)
\\\to z''(t)+4z(t) = \sin(2t)
$$
you can check that the general solution has the form
$$
z(t) = A\cos(2t) + B\sin(2t) - \frac 14 t\cos (2t)
$$

Now you can go back to the original variable.